# How to make generic of component necessary?

Tags: typescript

how to make generic of component necessary? For example, if I will delete < Employee > or < Device > from < ChildComponent / > in JSX, I want to get type error with the component < ChildComponent / >, something like this "Expected 1 type argument, but got 0."

```
interface Common {
    id: string;
}

interface ChildComponentProps<T> {
    renderFun: (item: T) => React.ReactNode;
}

const ChildComponent = <T extends Common, >(props: ChildComponentProps<T>) => {
    return <></>;
};

interface Employee extends Common {
    name: string;
    position: string;
    department: string;
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <ChildComponent<Employee>
                renderFun={(item) => <>{item.department}</>}
            />
        </>
    );
};

interface Device extends Common {
    model: string;
}

const OtherParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <ChildComponent<Device>
                renderFun={(item) => <>{item.model}</>}
            />
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: TS tried to infer something for the type parameter on a generic function/component. You can use something akin to a custom error:  https://tsplay.dev/WPzeKN